# What's the right way to expose a key-value pair in a restful web service?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, restful-url, restful-architecture

I'm building a restful web service and my backend happens to expose a key-value pair object.  For example, you can say:

```
String value = transientObject.get("key");
```

Right now the url for it is like this:

```
GET /transientObject/key
```

To set a value, you do

```
POST /transientObject/key
```

and pass the `value` in the body.

I've got lots of other calls in my api that return and accept complex objects, but this one doesn't fit that pattern in an obvious way.  I *could* change the api so that the GET and POST return and accept a new object that looks like this:

```
public class KeyValue {

    private String key;
    private String value;

}
```

This would be more consistent with the rest of my api, but it does make *this* call a little more annoying to make: Now you have to construct/deconstruct an object when you could just send/retrieve the value.

Should I stick with my current way or change the api to accept an object for consistency's sake?

Comment: If the keys were integers (e.g., auto-incremented ids) and the resource was simply the `String value` then you'd already be there. I think it only feels different because the keys are strings. Effectively it's no different from modifying `/user/1` (if the user were simply a name/string).

Comment: @SimeonVisser That makes sense (though I don't know if I like that analogy.  It's difficult to think of a user that's not a complex object)

Comment: It's not the best example but it goes to show the perspective. How about `/username/1`?

Comment: @SimeonVisser yeah that makes more sense, thanks